# How to set multiple variables in target makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have one problem. I cannot set multiple variables depending on target. I need to set two variables for example if makefile has been run with option cpp (target), two variables should be set,but I get only one variable  (CC) set. But another is left as default.

```
cpp:EXTENSION=cpp
cpp:CC=g++
cpp:COMPILE
```

Please help with this problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. What version of Make are you using? (If you're not sure, try `make -v`.) And a [minimal complete makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might save us some time.

Comment: This **cpp:COMPILE** is not a variable definition but a target definition in my GNU make and make complains about not finding the target COMPILE. If I leave it out all works as expected

Comment: Directly from the `make` documentation - `A variable name may be any sequence of characters not containing ':', '#', '=', or leading or trailing whitespace.`. Your above examples are not variables. Also, target-specific rules are only valid within that target, and in any dependencies of that target, unless overridden there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I cannot set multiple variables depending on target.

In [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), this is typically achieved by analyzing the content of the `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` variable and then setting the variables depending on the specified goals.

For example, a Makefile:

```
ifeq ($(filter cpp,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),cpp)
MSG=make cpp was called!
endif

ifeq ($(filter notcpp,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),notcpp)
MSG=make notcpp was called!
endif

all:
        @echo possible targets: cpp, notcpp; false

notcpp cpp:
        @echo $(MSG)
```

Running the `make cpp` would print `make cpp was called!`.

Running the `make notcpp` would print `make notcpp was called!`.

(Explanation of the `ifeq ($(filter cpp,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),cpp)` construct. The `$(filter)` function looks for the word (first argument, `cpp`) in the list (second argument, `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`). If it finds the word, it returns it. Otherwise, it returns an empty string. The `ifeq` then compares the result of the `$(filter)` function to the sought word: if equal, then the block til `endif` is parsed/executed. Alternatively, one could write `ifneq ($(filter cpp,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)` to test that the result of `$(filter)` is not an empty string. For more info, see [`$(filter)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-filter) and [`ifeq`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Syntax) in GNU Make documentation. Additionally, about [general function syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Syntax-of-Functions) and how to [call a custom function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function).)

Another possibility is using multiple Makefiles. In the main Makefile, depending on the target you pass the control to the target-specific Makefile, e.g.:

```
cpp notcpp:
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.$@ all
```

Use of target-specific [includes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include) is also a popular option.

Comment: Thx , works like a charm, can you please explain this line $(filter cpp,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),cpp)

Comment: Updated answer with an explanation.

Comment: Just to be clear, `filter` is more sophisticated than that: for `$(filter <list1>,<list2>)` it returns any instances of any word in `<list1>` that appear in `<list2>` (so the first list may be a single word, or multiple words).