# Multiple target specific variables in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

`Make` can't define multiple [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html).

But there is a macros from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50357925/5537840) that can solve the problem.

```
assign-vars = $(foreach A,$2,$(eval $1: $A))
```

But probably it can't set variable that depends on another variable. For example:

```
assign-vars = $(foreach A,$2,$(eval $1: $A))


multiple_variable = a=10 \
                    b=$(shell echo $$(( $(a)-1 )) )

$(call assign-vars, print, $(multiple_variable))

print:
    @echo a=$(a)
    @echo b=$(b)
```

I expected to see `b=9` as a result from `print` target but I get `b=-1`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: The problem is that Make sees `multiple_variable` as a list of space-separated strings. So `foreach` will split it up that way, *not* the way you had in mind. It works quite well for assignment statements *without* internal spaces. But even if the spaces weren't a problem, it's hard to see how any of this could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the entire contents of `multiple_variable` is expanded first, before the for-loop runs.  So, it's not possible to refer to earlier variables in the assignment of later variables: they won't be set yet.

When you run:

```
$(call assign-vars, print, $(multiple_variable))
```

the first thing make does, is expand the variable `multiple_variable`:  That expands to this:

```
a=10 b=-1
```

because when make goes to invoke the shell, the make variable `a` has not been set yet and so it runs `echo $(( -1 ))`.

I don't really know of a good way to do what you appear to want to do... although I'm not sure I understand what you want to do anyway.  It seems like you should take a step back and reconsider your requirements.

Comment: Apart from that,  `target_1: var_x = val_x` each on a separate line for an arbitrary number of `x`s does work, no?

Comment: Yes.  Each subsequent target-specific evaluation will be performed in the context of the previous ones for that target.  The problem here is that all the evaluation happens first, when the `call` function is evaluated and before they are made into target-specific variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite it to:

```
define newline


endef

assign-vars = $(eval $1: $(subst $(newline),$(newline)$1 :,$2))

define print_vars :=
a=10
b=$(shell echo $$(( $(a)-1 )) )
endef
```

that should do the trick.

EDIT: I only see now, that you are trying to calculate a target specific variable from anothen one. I don't think that will work, as I doubt that there is a specified order in which target specific variables are assigned. So `a` may or may not be defined when `b` receives its value.

Comment: No, they are defined in order as specified in the makefile.  This might work; nice!  Personally I think it's easier to read if you just write them out by hand but I guess if you're trying to assign them to lots of targets it might be better... we don't actually know what the real use-case is but I would probably choose a different option, such as recursive variable names or something.

Comment: @MadScientist ok, didn't know about the imposed order - I wouldn't use it though. The only order that I burden my maintenance programmer (mostly myself) with is the order for the phase 1 execution. Once the makefile is doing the rule evaluation stuff, evil monsters like parallelism are rearing up. Even if target specific variables are part of phase 1 (or something inbetween) they share the sin of being written like rules ;)